# Writing a test for a Django View get_context_data() method

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

I am writing a test for a View where I update context to pass additional information to the template.

## Problem

In writing the test, I'm having trouble accessing context from the RequestFactory.

## Code

#### View

```
class PlanListView(HasBillingRightsMixin, ListView):
    """Show the Plans for user to select."""

    headline = "Select a Plan"
    model = Plan
    template_name = "billing/plan_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlanListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            "customer": self.get_customer()
        })
        return context
```

#### Test

```
class TestPlanListView(BaseTestBilling):

    def setUp(self):
        super(TestPlanListView, self).setUp()
        request = self.factory.get('billing:plan_list')
        request.user = self.user
        request.company_uuid = self.user.company_uuid

        self.view = PlanListView()
        self.view.request = request
        self.response = PlanListView.as_view()(request)

    def test_get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(self.view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({"customer": self.view.get_customer()})
        self.assertEqual(
            self.view.get_context_data(),
            context
        )
```

## Question

How can I test the view's get_context_data() method?

Answer (score 11):

Using a [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#example) gives you access to your context.

```
def test_context(self):
    # GET response using the test client.
    response = self.client.get('/list/ofitems/')
    # response.context['your_context']
    self.assertIsNone(response.context['page_obj'])
    self.assertIsNone(response.context['customer']) # or whatever assertion.
    .....
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to test the full browser behavior you could use the [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/#example) instead. This factory provides a request instance that you can pass to your view. The benefit in my case was that I can test a single view function as a black box, with exactly known inputs, testing for specific outputs. Just as described in the docs.

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {'1': 11337}
        return context

# ...
def test_context(self):
    factory = RequestFactory()
    request = factory.get('/customer/details')
    response = TestView.as_view()(request)
    self.assertIsInstance(response.context_data, dict)
    self.assertEqual(response.context_data['1'], 1337)
```